# Is there a way to get all the test methods in a maven project

Tags: maven, testing, plugins, junit, testng

I am working on a project which requires me to get all the test methods under a project in maven. In other words, I need to get all methods that have @Test annotation. I wanted to check if there is a way/plugin which I can use to get it.

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: What is the purpose of that? If you need to read annotations you have to write it and analyse the source code...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Maven Surefire Report Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html)?

When I run `mvn surefire-report:report` an `index.html` is generated in the `/target/surefire-reports/` folder. Clicking on 'Chronological view' or 'Times' links, there is a report which lists every class and every method that was executed by surefire.  Looks like it should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
ag --skip-vcs-ignores --xml "<testcase name" | cut -d' ' -f 4,5 | awk '{ print $2 " " $1}' | sed 's/classname="//' | sed 's/" name="/#/' | sed 's/"//'
```

Gives:

```
aPackage.TestClass#testMethod1
aPackage.TestClass#testMethod2
```

... etc